# How to extract any string between SELECT and FROM in SQL query using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, regex

How to extract the string below using regex (preg_match or preg_replace):

`SELECT id FROM table WHERE 1` would match **" id "**

`SELECT name, (SELECT price FROM table2 WHERE id = '1') var FROM table1 WHERE 1` would match **" name, (SELECT price FROM table2 WHERE id = '1') var "**

Comment: I can easily do the first case but in the cases looking like the second one it gets " name, (SELECT price " instead of " name, (SELECT price FROM table2 WHERE id = '1') var " because of the FROM in the select clause

Comment: Regular expressions are not a suitable tool for this problem. Try https://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/ instead.

Comment: Also, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034100/get-the-select-block-of-a-sql-query-using-regex-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to do some advanced things with your queries, the best way is to use a sql parser ("php sql parser" for example, as suggested). To only get the content between SELECT and FROM, you can use this:

```
$test_queries = array(
    'SELECT id FROM table WHERE 1',
    'SELECT name, (SELECT price, (SELECT 1+1) FROM table2) var FROM table1',
    'SELeCT FROMAGE, \'\\\'((\', \'"\")(\', "\'\"\\\" FrOM table');

$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
 # definitions
 (?(DEFINE)
   # content inside quotes
   (?<quoted> (["']) (?> [^"'\\]++ | \\{2} | \\. | (?!\g{-1})["'] )*+ \g{-1} )

   # nested parenthesis
   (?<nested> ( \( (?> [^()"']++ | \g<quoted> | (?-1) )*+ \) ) )

   # content between SELECT and FROM
   (?<content> (?> [^(F"']++ | \BF | F(?!ROM\b) | \g<quoted> | \g<nested> )++ )
 )

 # pattern
 \bSELECT\b (?<result> \g<content> ) FROM\b
~xis
LOD;

foreach ($test_queries as $k => $test_query) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $test_query, $match))
        echo '<br/>' . $k . ') ' . trim($match['result']);
}
```